# Disable Spring Security /login/auth and define everything explicitly?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to setup a new project using Spring Security. When you do so every page is auto redirected to /login/auth. I read that you can disable this and instead explicitly state all controllers/routes. can someone point me in the right direction as far as how to obtain this? been searching forever and cant find it.

I first read about it in answer one of this question :

[Grails, Spring Security Core - remove /login/auth from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736282/grails-spring-security-core-remove-login-auth-from-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the section [Pessimistic Lockdown](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#pessimistic-lockdown) in the documentation will lead you to the fact you can reverse this behavior by using the following configuration:

```
// Config.groovy 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = true
```

This should accomplish what you are after. I recommend reading the documentation for this plugin as it is well written and covers a lot of useful information.